# php/jquery: posting form data

Tags: php, jquery, forms, formatting

i wrote a grid widget for editing data from a database and i'm looking for a more convenient way for sending the data to my saving-script.

the form contains textboxes and the following database structure:

```
recordID field         value      field           value
----------------------------------------------------------
1        first_name    andy        last_name      smith
2        first_name    tom         last_name      jones
3        first_name    john        last_name      connor
```

currently i'm adding the recordID to the fieldname, sending i this way:

```
first_name/1=andy&last_name/1=smith&first_name/2=tom.....
```

the problem is that on the server script i need to parse the recordID's for proper saving.
is there a more convenient way where i can wrap each record by its recordID?

```
such as: record1 = firstname:andy, last_name:smith | record2 = ... ?
```

i'm building the post string by jQuery.
thanks!

Comment: how to save data ..i.e. ajax or submit

Comment: [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form your data into an array (arrayOfData for this example), then you can use a jQuery ajax call to send it as a string to php (phppage.php in this example).  something like the following will work.  to use this you need JSON.js from [here](http://www.json.org/js.html) for the `stringify` function.

```
$.post("phppage.php",{
    fieldName:JSON.stringify(arrayOfData)
},function(return){
   //whatever
});
```

this will need to be parsed in php like

```
$incArray = json_decode(fieldName, true);
```

only an example, not all the work is done for you here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to name your fields like this:

```
records[1][first_name]=andy&records[1][last_name]=smith&records[2][first_name]=tom.....
```

Comment: nice idea but i assume i need to use eval() for converting it in php?

Comment: No. Php automatically converts names like this into arrays. So you can use $_POST['records'] in your script.